# Disabling Login Window on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I would like to know how to disable the login window [PICTURE A] when I start ArcMap ?

In the code I am starting ArcMap, but then I get prompted with username and password dialog.

How can I disable this dialog ?

Keep in mind that I have the save username and password in the ArcCatalog connections properties so that is not that issue here.

```
var mxDocument = new MxDocumentClass();  // This statment is where the login screen pops up and arcmap starts
arcMapApp = mxDocument.Parent;
if (arcMapApp == null)
  return
arcMapApp.Visible = false;
```

[image]

PICTURE A

Comment: Could you  be more specific? Are you opening a mxd with database connection?

Comment: I am simply starting arcmap using the code above, not specifying database connection or anything, the database connection login screen then pops as you can see in the picture above

Comment: i tried the same without no issue. The above code will just open the default mxd of the application. Did you try opening an mxd manually?

Comment: Yes I am always getting the same dialog. I am starting to think it has something to do with the other tools that are built on top of arcmap

Comment: Yeah. May be. its nothing related to the above mentioned code. Uninstall all the addin in your arcmap and try.

Comment: Entering the password in one application has no bearing on another. If the MXD references a layer based on a feature class in a database for which the password is not saved, you will always receive the login dialog.

Comment: but the mxd is new, it is using the default untitled mxd, I have not yet added any data

Comment: var mxDocument = new MxDocumentClass();  
 as soon as the code executes this statment, it starts arcmap, the debugger doesnt even get past this statment, it just pops the login menu

Comment: Maybe you've altered your default document?

Comment: Nope, I did enter username and password, and its the same old Untitiled document with no data, no layers nothing at all. I think it has something to do with Network Engineer Tools that are built on top of Arcmap